# Where can I buy English Region B Bluray for Arise - Pyrophoric Cult?

Tags: merchandise, ghost-in-the-shell-arise

I have tried everywhere for this!

Where can I buy the English Region B Bluray for Arise - Pyrophoric Cult?

Comment: [Amazon.co.UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ghost-Shell-Arise-Pyrophoric-Blu-ray/dp/B01CF2S7IC) and [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/Ghost-shell-pyrophoric-cult-Blu-ray/dp/B01MU7B71L) both have it. they both came up when i googled "Arise Pyrophoric Cult region B Bluray"

Comment: Please disregard my comment earlier because I thought the links above were English subbed. The ones @Memor-X mentioned only has French as subtitles, although it is indeed in region B/2. If I understand correctly and you want English audio and/or English subtitles, then I think your only option is this: http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/BCXA-999 It has English, Chinese and Japanese subs but only has Japanese audio track.

Comment: @W.Are ahhh yeh i see that now. must have mis-read it for English when i saw them because i know i checked to make sure they were Region B

Comment: @Memor-X Yeah. It also came up when I first searched for it and I, too, mistook the ones sold by Amazon as English at first, especially since region B/2 comprises English-speaking countries.

Comment: I spoke to Amazon support about bringing the English audio version to the UK but, I am not sure she recorded the query correctly... I also asked about getting CSI on Amazon video as other CBS shows are available on their platform in the UK 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking for Region B/2 Blu-rays, then they are available [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ghost-Shell-Arise-Pyrophoric-Blu-ray/dp/B01CF2S7IC) and [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MU7B71L), as mentioned by @Memor-X. If you are looking for those with Japanese audio and English subtitles, the only site I found that sells them can be found [here](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/BCXA-999).

If you are looking for a dubbed version, as far as I could find on the Internet, **no English dubbed version for this exists**. A [Reddit user claimed to have contacted Funimation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ghost_in_the_Shell/comments/4r4enu/pyrophoric_cult_update/) and their reply was:

> Sadly, we have not made any announcements about an English Dub of either the last two episodes of Alternative Architecture or the Pyrophoric Cult OVA at this time.

This was over 2 years ago and [a recent reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ghost_in_the_Shell/comments/6rpp6i/english_dubbed_films/) was supposedly similar:

> Sadly, we have not made any announcements about dubbing this movie at this time. Please continue to visit our site at http://www.Funimation.com/blog/ as we will post all new information there first!

Funimation is the licensor of this series so I suggest you contact them for updates (I can't as it's not available in my region). Amazon support can't help you much about this one as they can't make an English dubbed version available in their stores if it doesn't exist on the first place.

Comment: Yes however, on the USA Amazon Video store they offer the "Alternate Architecture" episodes all dubbed into English including the Pyrophoric Cult episodes so... 